# Is there an algorithm for selecting a set of items such that the result satisfies desired percentages of each attribute?

Tags: algorithm

Image I have a `people` table in my database. This table has the following columns:

`eye_color, gender, number_of_children`

Now I want to select a random set of `people`, such that the following conditions are met:

1. The total number of children must equal 20 ±1
2. The set must be 30% blue eyed, 20% green eyed, and 50% brown eyed (±5%)
3. The set must be 40% male, 60% female (±5%)

If a set of people does not exist to satisfy these requirements, I would like to know.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you tried so far?

Comment: This appears to be linear programming with constraints, or a multi-variate version of the set coverage problem.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of 2 general ways to approach this problem (asside from just trying until you luckily get a correct result).

One is to have an randomized algorithm that just solve the problem of finding a point on the boundary (or as close as possible to the boundary). This might not have good quality of ranndomness.

Second is to first randomly select a point on your the core formed from your linear constraints, and the secondly see if there is sufficient of such items in your database, if there is, select a random subset of them, otherwise randomly pick a new such point until you can complete the problem. Here the problem is the unbounded runtime.